# Cannot connect non primary database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot . Through tutorials, I have build an application . But when I try to connect 2 mysql database, I am successfull in connecting first DB, but for second the code always refer to the primary database and throws error that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: It's going to very difficult for anyone to answer your question properly without your code. Please can you supply a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that depend on requirements also.

- Create Two Datasource bean while both database url, username, pwd defined in property file. Read them through @Value and create @bean of both source

  ```
  @Value("${datasource.url}")
  private String url;

  @Value("${datasource.username}")
  private String username;

  @Value("${datasource.password}")
  private String password;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource1() {

      return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(username).password(password).url(url)
              .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource2() {

      return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(username).password(password).url(url)
              .build();
  }
  ```
- In case you have requirement to sync both database operations, I would suggest to use **JTA**

Comment: whatever you did in the sample code, I did .. but the non primary datasource also refers the primary database and throws table not found error

Comment: You need to change URL, username and pwd of another datasource...